# Is there a performance difference in using an OpenGL window like GLFW or a surrounding window like GTK or SDL?

Tags: c++, vlc, glfw

vlc has an impressive example showing how to integrate with gtk:

https://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc.git;a=blob;f=doc/libvlc/gtk_player.c

but we are using glfw and C++.  If we were to create a wrapper window using a windowing toolkit like gtk, is there any performance penalty in terms of the OpenGL operating within it?

Is it possible to open a video window within the GTKGL component, or does OpenGL interfere with video even if it is not rendering?

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the window handle to libvlc, I don't see why there would be performance differences.